# Ubuntu 13.10 won't restart unless Windows 8.1 is first started and then shutdown

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 13.10, windows-8, grub-efi

This is very strange. I have an Ubuntu 13.10/Windows 8.1 dual boot set up on my Asus N56VZ laptop. After shutting down Ubuntu, I can't restart it unless I first start and shutdown Windows 8. I'm not sure where to start on this. When I boot in recovery mode, it seems to hand on "loading initial ramdisk"

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to restart normally? You say you "can't"  do that, but you don't say what the symptoms are. Without some clue about what happens when it doesn't work, we can't do more than make wild guesses about the cause or solution.

Comment: Sorry. It loads the grub menu, I select Ubuntu and then I just get a black screen. When I select the advanced options and boot into Ubuntu recovery I at least seem to get some output but it never gets past "loading initial ramdisk." This happens whenever I shut down Ubuntu and restart or just select restart. The only way to make it boot again is to first select Windows 8 from grub and then do a normal Windows shutdown.

Comment: I also tried the steps at this link because it sounded similar to the problem I was having but no luck.

http://www.inforbiro.com/blog-eng/ubuntu-netbook-restart-problem/

Comment: This sounds like a hardware initialization problem, so I agree with LovinBuntu that adjusting firmware options is the first course of action.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out that the first boot option in the bios was for an installation of Ubuntu that was overwritten by the new one. Deleting that option in favor of the new one fixed the problem. Should have caught that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Fast Startup option in Windows as indicated [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html), and also possibly any QuickBoot option in your BIOS.